# collection view arrow button changes every reload data-which create unequal

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

edit the question-
in the storyboard the uibutton's image changes according to selected and default state, and even in loading not all buttons look same

```
    *@IBAction func topButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        if let delegate = self.delegate{
            delegate.topButtonTouched(indexPath: indexPath)}

    }
}
    here is the expend option

      func topButtonTouched(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if(screenType == .parameters){
        isExpanded[indexPath.row] = !isExpanded[indexPath.row]
        }else{
            isExpanedErrors[indexPath.row] = !isExpanedErrors[indexPath.row]
        }
       
       
    //    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ExpendeableCollectionViewCell
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        }, completion: {
            success in
            self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        
        })
    }*
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAoPO.png]

Comment: please read and consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you use reloadItems, you can save status "isOpen" for one cell and set it when reloadItems

Comment: thanks, @ phú dương hiển, I've tried that but when I do a reload data it always set the button state to it's default state.